# How can I write in math mode above and below equilibrium arrows with chemfigure?

Tags: chemformula

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \ch{E + S <=>[k_1][k_{-1}] ES}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want it to be:

[image]

Comment: `<=>[ $k_1$ ][ $k_{-1}$ ] `

Comment: Right. That works, as the chemformula package, see manual page 2, also loads Tikz ... https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula-manual.pdf